# Angular Reactive Form Value Changes

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-changedetection

I have a below form group in my student.component.ts:

```
        // Init locals
        this.studentFormGroup = this._fb.group({
            firstName            : ['N/A', {updateOn: 'change'}],
            lastName             : ['N/A', {updateOn: 'change'}],
            address              : ['N/A', {updateOn: 'change'}],
            phone                : ['N/A', {updateOn: 'change'}],
            gender               : ['N/A', {updateOn: 'change'}],
            email                : ['N/A', {updateOn: 'change'}],
            city                 : ['N/A', {updateOn: 'change'}],
            country              : ['N/A', {updateOn: 'change'}],
        });
```

on every control value changes, I do call a webapi and save it to database using the following way.
But I don't want to call webapi on **gender** field though user change its value.

```
this.studentFormGroup.valueChanges.subscribe(() => this.saveStudentRecord());
```

Here the problem is the above single line code call **saveStudentRecord** on every control value change.

But as I mentioned I don't need to call for **gender** control.

so currently I do follow the below way for value changes for each control

```
this.studentFormGroup.get('firstName').valueChanges.subscribe(() => this.saveStudentRecord());
this.studentFormGroup.get('lastName').valueChanges.subscribe(() => this.saveStudentRecord());
this.studentFormGroup.get('address').valueChanges.subscribe(() => this.saveStudentRecord());
..
..
and so on except **gender** field
```

But sometime if I have more controls in a single page I have to write these many statements to just ignore one field.

**Is it possible to ignore the gender control value change using the following way?**

```
this.studentFormGroup.valueChanges.subscribe(() => this.saveStudentRecord());
```

Comment: You do a web api call to save, on **EVERY** value change? So by the time I've typed in "Steve" you've attempted to save it 5 times?

Comment: what is the difference though? What happens if we say that gender is male, then user changes firstName, then `saveStudent()` is called with gender as `male`, then user changes gender to `female`, ok, function is not called, but if user again changes firstName then `saveStudent()` is called with gender female?

Answer (score 3):

This is a piece of cake...learn about rxjs and pipeable operators. (Code not tested)

```
this.studentFormGroup.valueChanges.pipe(
  distinctUntilChanged((prev, curr) => prev.gender !== curr.gender)), // don't emit value if gender changed
  debounceTime(500), // allow time between keystrokes (computers are too fast sometimes)
  takeUntil(this.destroyed$)
).subscribe(() => this.saveStudentRecord());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the keys (with `Object.keys()`) in `this.studentFormGroup.controls` and call `valueChanges.subscribe()` on each control *except* for the gender control.